# Determining total number of tickets sold

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say there is a lottery where ticket numbers 58,145,350, and 400 won. Is there a way to determine the most likely number of tickets sold? We are assuming non-replacement and fair draws.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds Like German Tank Problem:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem:
In the statistical theory of estimation, the problem of estimating the maximum of a discrete uniform distribution from sampling without replacement is known in English as the German tank problem, due to its application in World War II to the estimation of the number of German tanks.